# URL Query with JQuery .hide() function not working. Why?

Tags: jquery, url, hide

*I will update the title of this question after I fully understand what I am asking*

I am using the vimeo api to display an array of videos using JSON and uses the tags as classes. This is working fine.

However at the end of the script I want to hide any elements that don't match the query in the url.

```
var query = location.href.split('/#/').pop().split('/').join(" ");
```

I grab the query from the url (http://website.com/link/to/page/#/tag/tag/tag/tag = "tag tag tag tag") then check it against the classes of each result item.

```
// Find Parent & checks for query classes
var thisTile = tile.parent().parent(),
    matchesClass = thisTile.hasClass(query);

// If does hot have query as class then hides
if (matchesClass === false) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

**NOTE: Everything works except the part where it is supposed to hide the result item if it doesn't have the query classes.**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/Rt4pt/

Test Query: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/Rt4pt/show/#/basketball

Comment: which element do you exactly want to hide?

Comment: @Jignesh the parent container that the classes have been applied to.

Comment: what does `$(this)` refer to?

Comment: what I understand is if you want to use 'this'. you would have to be in that context of the element.

Comment: If you want to hide any specific element. you should use $(.classname).hide()  or if you know id of that element you need to use $(#idofthatelement).hide()

Comment: @Ohgodwhy As the script loads from the Vimeo API, it moves one array item at a time, `$(this)` refers to the current array item loading.

Comment: @Jignesh yeah obviously, but I'm trying to check the current item if it has the classes or not and if it doesn't then hide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an Javascript Object (from $.getJSON), not an HTML DOM Element.

```
console.log($(this));

Object
accepts: Object
async: true
cache: false
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: Object
converters: Object
crossDomain: true
dataType: "json"
dataTypes: Array[2]
flatOptions: Object
global: false
hasContent: false
isLocal: false
jQuery1800318833630066365_1344952134351: true
jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: undefined
processData: true
responseFields: Object
success: function (json) {
type: "GET"
url: "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/47175713.json?callback=jQuery1800318833630066365_1344952134351&_=1344952134490"
xhr: function createStandardXHR() {
__proto__: Object
```

I found that by adding two debug statments: http://jsfiddle.net/Rt4pt/6/

I am not sure what you want to hide, but try this

```
$('#' + json[0].id ).hide();
```

Comment: Oh I should've known that. What is the best way to select the HTML DOM element